# Most efficient way to count items under a nested tree

Tags: mysql, performance, tree

So I'm looking to provide a `category (x)` style product count on my website.

I'm currently using MySQL.

My categories table looks like:
`Categories (Id, TreeLeft, TreeRight, Level, Name)` - with 'Level' being the node depth.

Categories entered look like this:
[image]

My Item > Categories relation table looks like:
 `ItemCategories (ItemId, CategoryId)`

Assuming I have:

- 1 item under 'TUBE'
- 2 items under 'LCD'
- 1 item under 'FLASH'
- 1 item under '2 WAY-RADIOs'

How can I most efficiently query my items (large db) + categories (4000 in db), to produce:

```
Electronics (5) 
 - Televisions (3)
   - Tube (1)
   - LCD (2)
 - Portable Electronics (2)
   - MP3 Players (1)
    - Flash (1)
   - 2 Way Radios (1)
```

Taking note to only return those categories which have products in them and also correctly counts them up the tree.

Any help most appreciated.

Edit: DB Code to recreate environment locally:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Categories` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `TreeLeft` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `TreeRight` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `Level` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`),
  KEY `TreeLeft` (`TreeLeft`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

INSERT INTO `Categories` (`Id`, `TreeLeft`, `TreeRight`, `Level`, `Name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 20, 1, 'Electronics'),
(2, 2, 9, 2, 'Television'),
(3, 10, 19, 2, 'Portable Electronics'),
(4, 3, 4, 3, 'Tube'),
(5, 5, 6, 3, 'LCD'),
(6, 7, 8, 3, 'Plasma'),
(7, 11, 14, 3, 'MP3 Players'),
(8, 15, 16, 3, 'CD Players'),
(9, 11, 14, 3, '2 Way Radios'),
(10, 12, 13, 4, 'Flash');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ItemCategories` (
  `CategoryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ItemId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `CategoryId` (`CategoryId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `ItemCategories` (`CategoryId`, `ItemId`) VALUES
(4, 3442),
(5, 3441),
(5, 3456),
(9, 5343),
(10, 5423);
```

Comment: Usually tree must be done in programming language... Because it's much easier to get each menu level and count. Or use some recursive function.

Comment: Are the actual products held in a separate table? Either way consider providing a sample data set.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand the problem. Mike Hillyer's article on nested sets (from where this image originates) tells you exactly how to grab all the leaf nodes. From there, finding all products listed under each of those is trivial right?

Comment: @Justin - I have no idea what your trying to say here ?

Comment: @Strawberry - The problem is as stated, pulling a tree from the db which only shows nodes that have products in them, with the parent node talling up the product count as it builds the query. This is not on Mike Hillyers article (where the demo image is from).  ~ I have however put on db code to help anyone recreate the envionment locally.

Comment: @AndreeCrist I'm saying that you should use php or other programming languge with several mysql querys. One Query for each level probably. It's not easy in just one Query to get all menu...

Comment: @AndreeCrist, that is exactly what the first query under "Aggregate Functions in a Nested Set" in Mike's article does!?!

Comment: @Justin - see strawberry..

Comment: @Strawberry - your absolutely right. Don't know how I missed it. Feel like an idiot now. Thanks for pointing it out. Please if you submit the link to the solution, or the solution itself I can accept as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the subsection, entitled *Aggregate Functions in a Nested Set*, of Mike Hillyer's classic article on this subject at [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)